# Python3.6 How do I read line by line and split those lines on commas?

Tags: python-3.6

After spending a few hours trying to figure this out (From questions already asked and other places), I'm still stuck on it. The goal is to read from a text file (Have that working), line by line (Not working). As it stands, this is my latest attempt:

```
With open("Product.txt","r") as file:
    for i in file:
        lineRead = file.readline()
        productSplit = lineRead.split(",")
        productNameList.append(productSplit[0])
        productCostList.append(productSplit[1])
        productPriceList.append(productSplit[2])
```

What I am *trying* to do:

1. Read the text file line-by-line.
2. Split the result on commas.
3. Assign values at specific indexes to specific lists.

---

I'm not really sure how to use readline, and I couldn't understand it from the documentation, nor the other questions. I think that's where my problem is. I'd appreciate being told what I'm doing wrong. And as a side note, could I read in the whole file, split on the new line, and then split those indexes on commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
productNameList = []
productCostList = []
productPriceList = []
With open("Product.txt","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        productSplit = line.split(",")
        productNameList += [productSplit[0]]
        productCostList += [productSplit[1]]
        productPriceList += [productSplit[2]]
```